# My divs overlapping when resize my browser

Tags: html, css

I am very new to this and ive been trying to figure out a problem in my layout.
My div .containerstacks overlap on the right side when resizing.
How can i solve this?
And also if there is anything else that you think i should do different i would be glad to hear.

```css
`.actionscontainer {
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 178, 189);
  max-width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #161616;
}

` `.containerstacks {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #161616;
}

` `.buttonstacks {
  background-color: #161616;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

`
```

```html
<div class="actionscontainer">
  <div class="containerbuttons">
    <button id="act1" class="buttonactionrfi" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">RFI</p></button>
    <div class="infoaction">
      <p class="p2">(Open raise)</p>
    </div>
    <button id="act2" class="buttonactionrfi" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">vs.RFI</p></button>
    <div class="infoaction">
      <p class="p2">(Versus open raise)</p>
    </div>
    <button id="act3" class="buttonaction3bet" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">vs.3bet</p></button>
    <div class="infoaction">
      <p class="p2">(Versus 3bet)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerstacks">
    <button id="100bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">100BB</p></button>
    <button id="70bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">70BB</p></button>
    <button id="60bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">60BB</p></button>
    <button id="50bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">50BB</p></button>
    <button id="40bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">40BB</p></button>
    <button id="30bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">30BB</p></button>
    <button id="25bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">25BB</p></button>
    <button id="20bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">20BB</p></button>
    <button id="17bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">17BB</p></button>
    <button id="15bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">15BB</p></button>
    <button id="12bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">12BB</p></button>
    <button id="10bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">10BB</p></button>
  </div>
  <div class="containerposition">
    <button id="EP" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">EP</p></button>
    <button id="MP" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">MP</p></button>
    <button id="MP2" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">MP2</p></button>
    <button id="HJ" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">HJ</p></button>
    <button id="CO" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">CO</p></button>
    <button id="BTN" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">BTN</p></button>
    <button id="SB" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">SB</p></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to learn about responsive web design and media query at css to make you web page fit on all screen size

Comment: After editing your post into one snippet, I noticed that you have a few syntax errors. You have multiple grave characters in front of the class selector for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the extra characters you have in your snippet. I fixed them in the snippet below.

In order to get the behavior that you want, you need to set the `flex-flow` to `row wrap` so that your items will wrap to the next line.

Then you need to give the items a `flex` value of `1` in order to make them stay in their container.

```css
.actionscontainer {
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 178, 189);
  max-width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #161616;
}

.containerstacks {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #161616;
  flex-flow: row wrap;        /* Set to row wrap */
}

.buttonstacks {
  background-color: #161616;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;               /* Set flex to 1 */
}
```

```html
<div class="actionscontainer">
  <div class="containerbuttons">
    <button id="act1" class="buttonactionrfi" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">RFI</p></button>
    <div class="infoaction">
      <p class="p2">(Open raise)</p>
    </div>
    <button id="act2" class="buttonactionrfi" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">vs.RFI</p></button>
    <div class="infoaction">
      <p class="p2">(Versus open raise)</p>
    </div>
    <button id="act3" class="buttonaction3bet" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">vs.3bet</p></button>
    <div class="infoaction">
      <p class="p2">(Versus 3bet)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerstacks">
    <button id="100bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">100BB</p></button>
    <button id="70bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">70BB</p></button>
    <button id="60bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">60BB</p></button>
    <button id="50bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">50BB</p></button>
    <button id="40bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">40BB</p></button>
    <button id="30bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">30BB</p></button>
    <button id="25bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">25BB</p></button>
    <button id="20bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">20BB</p></button>
    <button id="17bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">17BB</p></button>
    <button id="15bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">15BB</p></button>
    <button id="12bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">12BB</p></button>
    <button id="10bb" class="buttonstacks" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">10BB</p></button>
  </div>
  <div class="containerposition">
    <button id="EP" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">EP</p></button>
    <button id="MP" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">MP</p></button>
    <button id="MP2" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">MP2</p></button>
    <button id="HJ" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">HJ</p></button>
    <button id="CO" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">CO</p></button>
    <button id="BTN" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">BTN</p></button>
    <button id="SB" class="buttonpos" onclick="highlight(this)"><p class="p1">SB</p></button>
  </div>
</div>
```